# It is necessary to launch my audit application

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis, writing, email

> I am requesting access to MS-Access. It is necessary to launch my audit application.

**Background:**
I received this e-mail from an internal employee. He's requested that MS-Access software be installed on his computer so that he can access an application necessary for him to audit claims.

*What bothers me is the second sentence.*

Given the background of the request and the requirement, does "it is necessary to launch my audit application" makes sense.

- How could he have re-phrased it better?

Comment: As of the past couple of decades it's increasingly common to ***launch applications*** (as opposed to the old days, when we always used to ***run programs***).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, the context alone is what enables you to understand exactly what the sentence means. When I read the title of the question (before reading the context), I naturally read the sentence with the most immediate meaning, which can be paraphrased as: “I need to launch my audit application” or “My audit application must be launched”.

This reading has the word *it* functioning as a ‘dummy subject’, i.e., a placeholder just standing in until the real subject of the sentence comes along. The real subject is the noun phrase headed off by the infinitive: *to launch my audit application*. Getting rid of the dummy subject and putting the real subject in its usual place, the sentence reads, “To launch my audit application is necessary”.

Oldbag’s suggestion of repeating the subject is good; one might add to it replacing the subject with *this* or, replacing the preceding period with a comma, *which*:

> (I am requesting access to MS Access.) This is necessary to launch my audit application.
>   (I am requesting access to MS Access,) which is necessary to launch my audit application.

The reason why this approach works is that whereas *it* can be either a dummy subject (as above) or a real subject (as intended here, referring anaphorically back to *access to MS Access*), neither *this* nor *which* can function as dummy subjects. They **must** be real subjects, which means that the infinitive phrase further ahead in the sentence **cannot** be the subject; that reading becomes impossible.

Apart from this approach, there are two very obvious ways to make the sentence unambiguous.

One is to use *needed* instead of *necessary*. Something that must be done is *necessary to do* (similar in structure to *important to do*, *dangerous to do*, etc.); but no such construction exists with *needed*: we cannot say that something is **needed to do*. Unambiguous is therefore:

> (I am requesting access to MS Access.) It is needed to launch my audit application.

Another way is to explicitly write out what type of *to*-infinitive we are dealing with here. In *necessary/important/dangerous to do*, the infinitive is simply lexically licensed by the preceding adjective; in *needed to do [something]*, on the other hand, we are dealing with an infinitive of purpose, describing the goal or purpose of the preceding statement.

Infinitives of purpose can be expanded by adding *in order* before *to*, so the following are also unambiguous:

> (I am requesting access to MS Access.) It is necessary in order to launch my audit application.
>   (I am requesting access to MS Access.) It is needed in order to launch my audit application.

Comment: +1, great effort, most would have waived this question off as off-reference.

Answer (score 2):

It does make sense - although I suppose it could be misunderstood. For absolute clarity: "MS-Access is needed to launch the application for claim audits."